# How do I import user input into a dictionary for which I'm creating a table

Tags: python-3.x

How do I collect the users input in this case the prices, and then import that into a dictionary which will allow me to display the data within a table using the tabulate module in python 3. So for example how can I get the users customs price instead the one that I put there.

```
 table1 = [['Gas Station Name', 'Price'], ['Shell', '3.23'], ['Texaco', '3.49'], ['BP', '2.98'], ['Sams Club', '3.02'], ['Kroger Gas', '3.12'], ['Cosco Gas', '3.91'] ]
print(tabulate(table1, headers='firstrow', tablefmt='grid'))
```

I have also tried this approach to collect the input from the user in which it outputs the list in the console but I'm not to sure if I'm going in the correct direction. Thanks.

```
lst1 = [] #function Creates an Empty List
print("Enter 5 Gas Station Prices:")
for i in range(5):
    lst1.append(eval(input()))
print(lst1)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried your approach?

Comment: When I tried that approach it worked as intended in which the user enters the prices and then the list is created however, Im stuck on how to get that output back into a dictionary.

Comment: What's the format of the dictionary? {"Gas Station Name": ["Shell", "Texaco"], "Price": ["3.23", "3.49"]} or {"Shell": "3.23", "Texaco": "3.49"}? Please detail your question.